# How to add cakephp in eclipse or net beans?

Tags: cakephp

**i AM New to cakephp framework**.

- I download the cakephp framwwork in separatly.
- Installed eclipse separatly in my local host.
- How to integrate cakephp in eclipse for new application.
- please tell me how to work with the cakephp in eclipse Ide.please give the right instructions.

**Thank you:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working in CakePHP you may use Netbeans 7.* or PhpStorm instead of eclipse. Thats IDE support you more than eclipse and have built in CakePHP feature.**

**If your IDE is not ready for PHP development , then goes through the way :**

- Open Eclipse and go to Help-> Software Updates-> Find and Install Select "Search for new features to install" and click "Next" Create a New Remote Site with the following details:

Name: PDT

- URL: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release
- Check the PDT box and click "Next" to start the installation

Hope it helps

**In eclipse you may try with this CakePHP Plugin For Eclipse**